# JSON files are included in the bundle

Tags: webpack

webpack include .json file in bundle

i try this

```
const data = require('./header.json');
```

if i use json-loader

```
{
  test: /\.json?$/,
  loader: 'json-loader',
  options: {
    name: '[hash].[ext]',
    publicPath: assetsPath + 'constants/',
    outputPath: 'assets/json',
  },
},
```

then I get the following error
Module parse failed: Unexpected token m in JSON at position 0 while parsing near 'module.exports = {"l...'
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.

I need after the build I can change json files

Comment: Are you sure that your `json` is valid?

Comment: yes, json is valid

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it helps, but you don't need json-loader for json files. You can use `file-loader` to import json files. It doesn't need any configuration. Just make sure that `file-loader` is installed.

Comment: if i use file-loader, i get at error
Module parse failed: Unexpected token m in JSON at position 0 while parsing near 'module.exports = __w...'
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.

Comment: That weird cause I have loaded json files in my apps with `file-loader`. Maybe the json file is not correct! Can you add your file here?